# QuickBuild: How can I create a builder to open a tarball package (tar.gz) whose name will change with each version?

Tags: maven-2, build-process, continuous-integration

I'm using PMEase QuickBuild to perform automated builds of our Maven2 projects and a nightly sanity test to ensure nothing is broken.

The test needs to untar packages which are created by the automated Maven2 projects. The problem is that the package names change frequently due to project versions being incremented all the time.

Does anyone know how I can configure QuickBuild to pick up the version (ideally from the POM file of the individual components), if this is possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an option for you but it looks like you can do it the other way around. Quoting [Build with Maven](http://wiki.pmease.com/display/qb2/Build+with+Maven):

> ### Control build version
>
> If you want to control the build
>   version from QuickBuild side, please
>   follow below steps:
>
> 1. Change the POM file and define the project version as
>      `${buildVersion}`. Do not forget to
>      commit the file into your SCM after
>      change.
> 2. Define a build property like below when define the Maven build
>      step:
>
>    ```
>    buildVersion=${build.version}
>    ```

There are maybe other options but I must admit that my knowledge (zero) of QuickBuild is very limited

Comment: Thanks, that is one solution but it is not the ideal option for me as I would prefer to use the version from the POM files instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I created a work around to this issue by having QuickBuild execute a shell script which did the untarring by using wildcards, similar to the following (to avoid computing the exact version):

tar xzf filename-*.tar.gz

I couldn't figure out how to do this in QuickBuild, so I offloaded the work to the shell script.